# UIImage becomes NSNumber

Tags: ios, ios6, uiimageview, uiimage, appdelegate

I am trying to save UIImage to app delegate. When I load that UIViewController for the first time, it returns UIImage(see first screen shot).

Help me ! Stuck here for almost 2 days.

[image]

But when I redirect back to that controller, UIImage becomes NSNumber. (see second screen shot)
[image]

Before I leave the controller I set the image to app delegate as follows

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.imageView.frame.size,YES, 0.0);
[self.imageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

del.getImage = resultingImage;
```

Comment: `getImage = resultingImage`? shouldn't that be `image = resultingImage`?

Comment: You really should not be calling your property "getImage", xcode might mistake it with a getter. Try changing that name to "myImage" or something like that, see if that works.

Comment: Try running your code with NSZombies enabled. When object of IntendedType is shown as TotallyUnrelatedType, it usually means that that object's memory was already freed.

Comment: getImage change to myImage also doesn't work. After NSZombies enabled, i got this error [UIImage retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1f2adad0

Comment: Ok this is stupid ~ but after I change my UIImage in app delegate to retain ~ it works ! Thanks everyone :)

Comment: Note that LLDB still gets confused about the contents of variables sometimes, although this one was likely a zombie.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is most easily solved using the debugger. First, as the comments said, change the property name to say myImage. Then, in your UIViewController class, provide you own setter:

```
- (void)setMyImage:(UIImage *)myImage
{
    NSLog(@"Image class: %@", NSStringFromClass([myImage class]));
    if([myImage isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
        NSLog(@"YIKES: a number!");
    }
    _myImage = myImage; // assumes ARC
}
```

Put a breakpoint on the second NSLog, or both. When you hit the second breakpoint, look at the call stack and you will find out who is setting it.